# Force GraphViz to align subgraphs one below other

Tags: graphviz, subgraph

I have a graph with 3 subgraphs that are placed one along the other, I want them to be stacked one on top each other (I don't want the direction of the content of the subgraph to change).

The simple example:

```html
digraph G {
rankdir=TB;
    subgraph cluster_lkg{
        subgraph cluster_sentence_1{
            "A1","A2","A3"
            "A1" -> "A2"
            "A1" -> "A3"
        }
        subgraph cluster_concepts_1{
            "B1","B2","B3"
            "B1" -> "B2"
            "B1" -> "B3"
        }
    }
    subgraph cluster_fkgs{
            "C1","C2","C3"
            "C1" -> "C2"
            "C1" -> "C3"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect the clusters (or, more precisely, the nodes within the clusters) in order to make your `rankdir = TB` effective. You can do so by using invisible edges:

```
digraph G 
{
    rankdir=TB;    
    subgraph cluster_lkg
    {
        subgraph cluster_sentence_1
        {
            "A1","A2","A3"
            "A1" -> "A2"
            "A1" -> "A3"
        }
        subgraph cluster_concepts_1{
            "B1","B2","B3"
            "B1" -> "B2"
            "B1" -> "B3"
        }
        //A1 -> B1;
    }
    subgraph cluster_fkgs
    {
            "C1","C2","C3"
            "C1" -> "C2"
            "C1" -> "C3"
    }
    edge[ style = invis ];
    { A2 A3 } -> B1;
    { B2 B3 } -> C1;
}
```

which yields

[image]

The node `C1` is misaligned - I guess this comes from the nesting the clusters but I have no recipe against it. Hope it helps anyway.